# How to get the last parameter requested by a certain url in PHP

Tags: php, android

I am developing an android app, which uses maps to show the seller's location and user's location as they walk or get on a car, or ride a moto, etc. So, I was using a class in android, which sends an Url request . passig the latitude and longitude as parameters to the server in a GET method every 5 seconds, example: site.com.br?latitude1000&longitude2000. My question is how do I retrieve the last sent informations of the user's location from the server in real time, so that, I can get them and mark in the map, in the user's smartphone?

Comment: You could use websockets. Im workin in a project based on RatchetPhp.
You'd recieve the get request and then make a push to the websocket server, then you send the message to your android client.

Link to ratchet (w/ examples) http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question in the right way .

This is a very bad practice.

However , you can save it in a session .

In the 5 sec Get request save it in a session variable that is unique to each user

```
$_Session['long']=$long;
$_Session['lat']=$lat;
```

Never save the entire get variable nor all the requested url ,also  all variables stored in session should be sanitized. 
to get the variables again in any other request.

```
$long=$_Session['long'];
$lat=$_Session['lat'];
```

there is still much more approaches to complete the task ,  why not send them again in the next request?

**The right way**
should be using web-socket , if you have the access to a vpn or a any service where you can install or use web-socket I recommend it as a must ,  sending request every 5 sec will have a lot of delay plus you will over load your server , also to mention the user will waist his valuable internet data plan

in brief with php websocket is a realtime 2 way way connection . I won't explain it here as it is off-topic

Comment: Hello friend, How do I send the location of both users and sellers to a web server, such as AWS, or other kinds of hosting services?

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by that ? you mean sending multiple variables in a single request ?